# Caching Bitmaps in a Appwidget

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, android-widget, android-appwidget

I am building an AppWidget which I'm hoping to be skinnable by allowing the user to download skins from a central repository.

I am copying the pngs that make up a skin into the widget's private directory.  I was loading the bitmaps from this directory and making Bitmaps that I stored in a static HashMap in order to avoid loading them each time.

I've realised that this will not work as the HashMap is garbage collected at some point (several hours later typically).  I realise it would be possible to load the Bitmaps from disk each time, but this will most likely be slow and drain the battery.

Is there a better way of caching this kind of data?

Comment: Hopefully not too slow - how large are the bitmaps?  Once you get the file loaded from disk, is the user going to be re-skinning often enough that is a performance issue?

Comment: @sqrfv The user will only change the skin when creating the widget.  The bitmaps are pretty small around 2k each, but there may be up to 100 per skin.  I think ~200k / skin is acceptable.  I would like to keep it in memory if possible rather than loading them all on each widget update.  Perhaps loading them all is more correct, but it feels like it would be slow

Comment: Sure, once you load the textures, you should be able to keep them in a map like you said.  Garbage collect won't recover an object unless the reference to the object is no longer direct, or gets lost. So, just make sure you keep a reference to the current skin on the widget's activity and gc won't take remove the map.

Comment: @sqrfv Hmm, I held the static data in the AppWidgetProvider and it seemed to get garbage collected (it became null).  So creating a static variable on the configuration Activity should work you think?

Comment: If you had a reference, the gc wouldn't have done that, it must have been something else.  Also, I highly recommend using messages or instance variables over statics, only use statics as a design element; and not as a way to tunnel in access from one section of code to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the source code for Google's standard "Power control" Widget

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/widget/SettingsAppWidgetProvider.java

I figured out that I need to set `DONT_KILL_APP` in `onEnabled`

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName("com.android.settings", ".widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

and unset it again in onDisabled

```
@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName("com.android.settings", ".widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

This seems to work properly for me, the settings were retained overnight (they weren't previously).